# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'precision' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, typeerror

I am using Amcharts for representing my values in Column chart.
Here is my code snippet:

```
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "Title";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    chart.valueAxes= [{
        "gridThickness":0,
    }];
    chart.categoryAxis.gridThickness= 0;
    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 0;
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "value";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.depth3D = 15;
    chart.angle = 30;

    var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
    chartCursor.cursorAlpha = 0;
    chartCursor.zoomable = false;
    chartCursor.categoryBalloonEnabled = false;
    chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);
    chart.creditsPosition = "top-right";
    chart.write("chartdiv");
```

My problem is that, whenever I hover the column, balloon text does not appear. Instead in console I get the error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'precision' of undefined in
>   amcharts.js:21 AmCharts.formatNumber amcharts.js:21
>   AmCharts.formatValue amcharts.js:28
>   AmCharts.AmSerialChart.AmCharts.Class.formatString serial.js:25
>   AmCharts.ChartCursor.AmCharts.Class.updateCursor amcharts.js:178
>   AmCharts.ChartCursor.AmCharts.Class.setPosition amcharts.js:170
>   AmCharts.ChartCursor.AmCharts.Class.detectMovement amcharts.js:161
>   (anonymous function)

I have added both `serial.js` and `amcharts.js`. But still I keep on getting error, which prevents me from showing balloon text.What should I do now?

Comment: Are you loading the libraries in the required order? ancharts first, immediately followed by serial?

Comment: @Stuart Yes, I am loading the libraries in required order. Still I face this error.

Comment: Check if you use the latest serial.js and amcharts.js files. We did changed some things in the latest version and this error is usually caused when one of the files is form the old version. It might also be cached.

Comment: @zeroin Thanks for your info. When I used latest js it worked. I just bought Amcharts a month ago. How can I now upgrade to the latest one?

Comment: Simply login to our support area: http://www.amcharts.com/support/ and you will get access to the latest files.

Comment: @zeroin am using the latest version and I still get the same error. Currently on version 3.13.0

loading in this order
amcharts.js + serial.js + themes/dark.js + ammap.js + maps/js/worldLow.js